# Loop through ContentControls from word in my specified order

Tags: c#, ms-word

I currently want to loop through a word document in the right order. For this i tried if & switch statements. It still just categorizes it through the order in the word document.  This is just an example. The output in my case becomes "blabla1","blabla2","blabla3"  etc.  Instead i want it to be "blabla2","blabla1","blabla3" Any suggestions?

```
namespace KontraktTilTekst {
 public partial class Form1: Form {
  public Url url = new Url();
  public bool[] success = new bool[2];

  public Form1() {
   InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   url.FileExist = File.Exists(url.WordPath) ? true : false; //Tjekker om urlen er der
   if (url.FileExist) {
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(url.TxtFileName)) //Tjekker om feltet til notepadfilen ikke er tomt
    {
     StreamWriter NotepadFile = new StreamWriter(url.TxtPath);
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new ApplicationClass();
     object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
     object path = url.WordPath; // <-------- Path where document is
     object readOnly = false;
     Document document = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly, ref miss, ref miss,
      ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss,
      ref miss, ref miss);


     word.Documents.Open(url.WordPath);
     foreach(ContentControl ff in document.ContentControls) {
      if (ff.Title == "something2") {
       NotepadFile.Write("blabla2");
      } else if (ff.Title == "something1") {
       NotepadFile.Write("blabla1");
      } else if (ff.Title == "something3") {
       NotepadFile.Write("blabla3");
      }
     }
     NotepadFile.Close();
     document.Close(ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);
     word.Quit();
    } else {
     MessageBox.Show("Husk at give txt filen et navn");
    }
   } else {
    //MessageBox.Show(url.FileExist.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show("Prøv med en anden sti");
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a separate function to find the ContentControl with a specified title inside the document. And then call this function in the order of the titles that you want to see.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Document wordDocument = ....;/// Your code to open document

    if(HasContentControlWithTitle(wordDocument, "something2"))
    {
        NotepadFile.Write("blabla2");
    }
    if(HasContentControlWithTitle(wordDocument, "something1"))
    {
        NotepadFile.Write("blabla1");
    }
    if(HasContentControlWithTitle(wordDocument, "something3"))
    {
        NotepadFile.Write("blabla3");
    }
}

bool HasContentControlWithTitle(Document wordDocument, string title)
{
    ContentControl result = GetContentControlByTitle(wordDocument, title);
    return result != null;
}

ContentControl GetContentControlByTitle(Document wordDocument, string title)
{
    ContentControl result = null;

    foreach(ContentControl ff in wordDocument.ContentControls)
    {
        if(ff.Title == title)
        {
            result = ff;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks! 
It worked liked a charm. 
I added a extra function to return the text back.